# requestLayout() improperly called by ListView

Tags: android, android-layout, listview

Estou com o seguinte erro, quando eu chamo minha tela de categorias elas carregam normalmente, vou pra segunda tab chamada despesa que carrega uma lista, até aí tudo bem, ao voltar pra primeira tab, o logcat fica que nem louco repetindo a seguinte mensagem:

```
06-11 18:46:20.770    4961-4961/com.prjctt.allan.newfinance W/View﹕ requestLayout() improperly called by com.prjctt.allan.newfinance.ExpandedListView{225d8596 VFED..C. .F....ID 0,86-316,209 #102000a android:id/list} during layout: running second layout pass
06-11 18:46:20.795    4961-4961/com.prjctt.allan.newfinance W/View﹕ requestLayout() improperly called by com.prjctt.allan.newfinance.ExpandedListView{225d8596 VFED..C. .F...... 0,86-316,209 #102000a android:id/list} during second layout pass: posting in next frame
06-11 18:46:20.834    4961-4961/com.prjctt.allan.newfinance W/View﹕ requestLayout() improperly called by com.prjctt.allan.newfinance.ExpandedListView{225d8596 VFED..C. .F....ID 0,86-316,209 #102000a android:id/list} during layout: running second layout pass
06-11 18:46:20.867    4961-4961/com.prjctt.allan.newfinance W/View﹕ requestLayout() improperly called by com.prjctt.allan.newfinance.ExpandedListView{225d8596 VFED..C. .F...... 0,86-316,209 #102000a android:id/list} during second layout pass: posting in next frame
06-11 18:46:20.901    4961-4961/com.prjctt.allan.newfinance W/View﹕ requestLayout() improperly called by com.prjctt.allan.newfinance.ExpandedListView{225d8596 VFED..C. .F....ID 0,86- 16,209 #102000a android:id/list} during layout: running second layout pass
06-11 18:46:20.928    4961-4961/com.prjctt.allan.newfinance W/View﹕ requestLayout() improperly called by com.prjctt.allan.newfinance.ExpandedListView{225d8596 VFED..C. .F...... 0,86-316,209 #102000a android:id/list} during second layout pass: posting in next frame
06-11 18:46:21.039    4961-4961/com.prjctt.allan.newfinance W/View﹕ requestLayout() improperly called by com.prjctt.allan.newfinance.ExpandedListView{225d8596 VFED..C. .F....ID 0,86-316,209 #102000a android:id/list} during layout: running second layout pass
```

Poderiam me ajudar? Estou o dia inteiro com esse erro.
Detalhe, o emulador fica bem lento quando o logcat fica daquele jeito..

gif para melhor entendimento :
[image: erro request]

Classe da ListView customizada

```
   public ExpandedListView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}


@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    if (getCount() != old_count) {
        old_count = getCount();
        params = getLayoutParams();
        params.height = getCount() * (old_count > 0 ? getChildAt(0).getHeight() : 0);
        setLayoutParams(params);
    }

    super.onDraw(canvas);
}
}
```

xml da lista

```
<com.prjctt.allan.newfinance.ExpandedListView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeightLarge"
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:scrollbars="none"
    android:padding="0dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/btAddSubCat"/>
```